# address bar url is getting appended to requested static resource on refreshing the page, how to handle this?

Tags: node.js, express

When I go to localhost, it gets redirected to localhost:8000/landing as expected and the static resource are served properly as can be seen in the below image

[image]

**Requested url** is https://localhost:8000**/3.bundle.js**

but the problem arise when I refresh the page on certain address, as it can be seen in below screenshot, address bar url is being attached to static resource

[image]

**Requested url** is https://localhost:8000**/landing/asdfa/3.bundle.js**

**/landing/asdfa** is being attached to requested static resource **3.bundle.js**

and it is resulting in returning wrong resource i.e, html

[image]

as my node routing is as follows

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/public'));
 app.use('/api',routes);
 app.get('*', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/public/index.html');
 });
```

---

***how to avoid or handle the address bar url being attached to the static resource request ?***

Comment: Please elaborate your issue, I can't get what you're saying.

Comment: How are you redirecting the request?

Comment: for all the wild entry I'm reaching **app.get('*')** .......
which is as expected but It would cause me a issue when the browser asks for the resource 3.bundle.js appended with the address bar url landing/anything/anything and it would not be able to serve 3.bundle.js and as specified it would end up serving index.html instead of the static resource 3.bundle.js